# How get access to purpose instance of class and pass data?

Tags: java, android, oop

The example code found on https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare. I create four instance of **CheeseListFragment**.  I cannot understand how to gain access to the third instance of the class and **pass the data**?  Particularly to the third

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CheeseListFragment.OnDataPass {
     Adapter adapter;

...
      adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
                adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), items[i]);
            }
...

 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                onDataPass(String.valueOf(position)); // how send data to third instance of CheeseListFragment 





     static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitles = new ArrayList<>();



        public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitles.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {


            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitles.get(position);
        }
    }
}




public class CheeseListFragment extends Fragment {

    List<News> lnews;
    private RecyclerViewAdapter mRecyclerviewAdapter;
    OnDataPass dataPasser;

...
    protected String[] mDataset;



    public interface OnDataPass {
        public void onDataPass(String data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        dataPasser = (OnDataPass) a;

    }
    public void passData(String data) 
        dataPasser.onDataPass(data);
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(2);
CheeseListFragment cheesyFragment = (CheeseListFragment) fragment;
cheesyFragment.onDataPass(...) // how pass data?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the third fragment by using the `getItem()` method in the adapter. In your case by calling `adapter.getItem(2)`.

Assuming you don't just want to add to find a fragment by the position, you could also add an additional method to your adapter to get the fragment by the title.

```
public Fragment getFragmentByTitle(String title) {
    if (!mFragmentTitles.contains(title))
        return null;

    return mFragments.get(mFragmentTitles.indexOf(title));
}
```

As for passing data to CheeseListFragment, you don't have to use an interface as in your example code, just add a public method `onDataPass()` to the CheeseListFragment class and call that when you get the fragment.

Comment: i want pass data to purpose Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(2); CheeseListFragment cheesyFragment = (CheeseListFragment) fragment; fragment. cheesyFragment.onDataPass(...)

Comment: @mehelta Amended my answer, hopefully that answers the second part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(2);
```

But then you need to cast to cheese:

```
CheeseListFragment cheesyFragment = (CheeseListFragment) fragment;
```

Now you have 3rd cheese fragment.

Comment: yep. cheesyFragment.onDataPass(...)